# "UnexpectedValueException" - error while crerate a new project

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to create a new project in Laravel yesterday but I have a problem. If i put "laravel new project", it will display this error

> [UnexpectedValueException]
>   Could not parse version constraint project: Invalid version string
>   "project"

If I want create a new project via composer "composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project", it will return this error

> [ErrorException]
>   "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to
>   use "     continue 2"?

But in this situation project will be create but I have w problem with run it,
I write "php artisan serv" and it return this

> PHP Warning:  require(/home/michal/project/vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/michal/project/artisan on line 18 PHP Stack trace: PHP   1.
>   {main}() /home/michal/project/artisan:0 PHP Fatal error:  require():
>   Failed opening required '/home/michal/project/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/michal/project/artisan on
>   line 18 PHP Stack trace: PHP   1. {main}()
>   /home/michal/project/artisan:0

How I can solve my problem?
PS. My composer version is 1.5.6

Comment: Did you install composer when you created your project? run `composer install` in your console

Comment: Yes. My composer version is 1.5.6. It works before (the latest project I created a few month ago) so I thought that I need update the composer but it's in the latest version

Comment: Not the composer itself, but composer in your project. Run `composer install` inside your project that you created.

Comment: I tryed and it'll return this error
`
[ErrorException]                                                             
  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "  
  continue 2"?                                                                 
                   
`

Comment: Visit this [link](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7783). Maybe you can find your solution there. I think your composer is not updated to latest version. Check their official website to see what's the latest version.